# Can we get communtiy ads?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[Community ads](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) allow a stack exchange site to advertise various community resources on the side bar. For example, we could advertise the reddit community, or the forum funding system. We can also advertise other projects that the monero community thinks are note worthy, such as i2p or the EFF.

Could we enable community ads on this site? (All that needs to be done is for a mod to make a post tagged [community-ads](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads), and then we submit our ads as answers.)

Comment: I tentatively really like the idea and will plan to respond in the next 24 hours after doing some more research.

Comment: @2quick4u Here's an example, btw: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads

Answer (score 1):

Okay I started a new `community-ads` [question](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120/community-promotion-ads-2016) based on my understanding of the process. People can start posting ad ideas right away!

EDIT: nvm

Comment: No, you can't do it. Only SE employee (usually CM like Grace Note) can start Community Ads on a site, as it requires special template to be added. (Please delete that "question")

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh, whoops. Sorry 2quick 4u.

Comment: @PyRulez No worry. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248216/152859) for official response about this.

Comment: You miss my point @2quick4u. If users will post answers on the question you started, nothing will happen. There will be no ads, those users will just waste their time. That's why I suggested to delete it, until this will be properly added by SE employee.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248214/how-do-we-get-community-promotion-ads-on-beta-sites/248216#248216) which I just read for the first time. Is there any harm in asking the question? It seems like the best way to test community demand for community ads is to allow for their creation and voting. Would that information not be helpful to someone considering whether or not to enable them for beta site?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I wished the blog post or the tag wiki said that. They just said "post ads to questions tagged [tag:community-ads] to make ads appear", basically. `:P`

Comment: @2quick4u if you do that, make it clear that it's tentative.

Comment: @2quick4u not sure, it might not be possible to "migrate" the ads created before the ads system is put in place, and all the work will be lost, requiring everyone to post the ads again, and vote again. Better ask Grace Note in a comment or in chat (e.g. TL), and delete the question until you get an answer, in the very least.

Comment: @ShadowWizard will do thanks

Comment: Cheers, and good luck with having it added to this site. :-)